# calculating probability, people in a row

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are total of n people, among whom A and B, stand in a row.

Q1: P(exactly r people between A and B)=?

Q2: Instead of in a row, they stand in a ring. 
    P(exactly r people between A and B)=?

For Q1, I am only this far, which is not too far..(LOL): $\binom{n-2}{r}\times r!$ for the combination for people between A and B. (......A,r people,B...).But I don't know how to handle the combination for the two sides, to the left of A and to the right of B.

For Q2, honestly I cannot tell how the combination could be different but I know they should be different.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: You are not all that bad.  You could choose r people in ${(n-2)\choose r}$ ways and you can arrange them in the middle in r! ways and the rest (n-r-2) could be arranged around A and B in (n-r-1)! and finally A and B could be permuted in 2 ways, The total number of ways is n! ways.  Thus, the probability is $ \dfrac{{(n-2)\choose r}. r!. (n-r-1)! 2!}{n!}$.  This reduces to David's answer.

Comment: @satishramanathan, thanks so much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$1)$ Assume $A$ stands ahead of $B$. By symmetry you then multiply by $2$. $A$ can be in positions $1,2,...,n-r-1$. The remaining can be configured in $(n-2)!$ ways. So the probability is $$\dfrac{2(n-r-1)(n-2)!}{n!}$$

$2)$ Call some position in the ring slot $1$ and number them clockwise. No matter where $A$ is, there can be $r$ people between $A$ and $B$ in two different ways, unless $r=n/2-1$. They are slots $A+r+1$ and $A+n-(r+1)$. Further, $A$ can occupy slots $1$ through $n$.

So if $r\neq n/2-1$ the probability is

$$\dfrac{2n(n-2)!}{n!} = \dfrac{2}{n-1}$$

else

$$\dfrac{n(n-2)!}{n!}=\dfrac{1}{n-1}$$

Comment: thanks so much. I got one further question for (1). Is the the assumption "A stands ahead of B" forcing B taking the very last position, and A taking any position from the 1st to the (n-r-1)th. So "the remaining has "(n-2)!"? Thanks again.

Comment: I'm counting the ways for $B$ to be ahead of $A$ (or behind depending which end is "first") by $r$ people. This happens in $n-r+1$ ways. Similarly, count the number of ways for $A$ to be ahead of $B$, same thing. Hence the $2$ in the numerator.

Comment: yes, I understand where "2" is coming from, wondering if I understand the term "(n-2)!" correctly. thanks~~

Comment: Those are the configurations of the other people for each configuration that has $A$ and $B$ being $r$ people apart.

Comment: is that B's position is decided when the position for A is decided, that B is r people behind A. And the remaining (n-2) people just take whatever seat they want, so (n-2)! (I think I got it, LOL)

Comment: Yep you got it.

Comment: I'm trying to understand (2). I get you said "if r=n/2-1, then A and B will be r people apart in either direction." if r is not n/2-1, then A and B will be r people apart on one way, and n-r-2 people apart the other way. But I don't quite understand why you said "They are slots A+r+1 and A+n−(r+1)." Could you say a little bit more? Thank you.

Comment: Think of a clock, the number positions being potential slots for $A$ and $B$. If $r=2$ and $A=1$ (one o'clock), $B$ can be placed at $4 = A+r+1$ or $10=A+12-(r+1)$. Since $r\neq 5 = n/2-1$ we will always get $2$ places $B$ can reside, no matter where $A$ is placed, hence the $2n$ in the numerator. Now consider $r=5$. If $A$ is placed anywhere, $B$ is already determined.

Comment: You are dividing by n! to find the probability of Part II. Don't you think it is (n-1)! for a circular configuration.  Let me know

Comment: That is only if we consider rotations by $2\pi/n$ the same configuration. In this case the numerators would be $2(n-2)!$ and $1(n-2)!$ with a denominator of $(n-1)!$. But the answer is the same

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit more straightforward line of thinking about the first part is to count first in how many ways a group of adjoining elements of size $r$ can be placed in the given row. Clearly, none of elements of the group can't take first or last place of the row (otherwise we couldn't fit $A$ or $B$) so there are only $n-2$ places left for use. Considering some particular cases we can quickly conclude that the block of $r$ elements can be placed in $(n-2)-r+1 = n-r-1$ ways. The group of r elements that will sit between A and B is simply an $r$-permutation of set $n$ without A and B, i.e. those men can be chosen in $(n-2)_r$ ways from $n-2$. The A and B encloses this group in 2 ways (A from left, B from right and vice versa). The rest of $n-r-2$ elements can fill rest of the places in $(n-r-2)!$ ways. The sample space is clearly all possible permutations of set $n$, which size is $n!$.

Hence,

$$p = \frac{2(n-r-1)(n-2)_r(n-r-2)!}{n!} = \frac{2(n-2)_r(n-r-1)!}{n!}$$

Regarding second part, it may be useful to enumerate the circle and consider sample space as all possible tuples (place of $A$, place of $B$) which size is $2$-permutations from set n which is equal to $(n)_2$. Brief inspection reveals that no matter how many elements there are between $A$ and $B$, the group can be rotated $n$ times to produce different positions. Taking into account relative position of A against B, the number of ways to place $A$ and $B$ in the circle to have $r$ elements between them is 2n.

Hence,

$$ p = \frac{2n}{(n)_2} = \frac{2}{n-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Is it okay if I take the denominator as $^{n}P_{2}.$ My logic is that we are essentially searching for the permutations that $A$ and $B$ can have in a circular ring of $n$ people. The numerator would be $2n,$ because for each n ways in which $A$ can be arranged, $B$ can be arranged in two ways - giving us a total of $2n.$ 
So the answer becomes  $\frac{2n}{^{n}P_{2}}.$

The answer gives me $\frac{2}{n-1} ...$ but I wanted to know if the thought pattern was right ?. If not, where am I going wrong!